# Css force button to be in the bottom of absolute div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im wondering if there any way to force a div that is after absolute position div without set is height to stay in the bottom and dont become on the absolute div?

this is the code:

```css
    .wrap {
      position: relative;
    }
    .ab {
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ab row">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button>push me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this to find if element is position absolute:

```js
//check if prev element child has position absolute like your OP
var pos = $(".row").prev().children(".ab").css("position");

if (pos == "absolute") {
  //take the height of the element
  var height = $(".row").prev().children(".ab row").css("height");
  //change element that contains button top position
  $(".row").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "top": height
  });
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.ab {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ab row">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button>push me</button>
</div>
```

I created also somethng more generic to match any element that may has absolute position:

```js
$(".row").prev().find("*").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("position") == "absolute") {
    var height = $(this).css("height");
    $(".row button").css({
      "position": "relative",
      "top": height
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.ab {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ab row">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button>push me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see is what you are expecting

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.ab {
    position: absolute;
}


.row {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```